# Android - how to determine when bitmap loaded to ImageView gets displayed?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview, android-glide

I'm working on Android (6.0) app that needs to display images on additional screen (connected via HDMI port). It's done by using Glide library and Presentation class. Glide provides "onResourceReady" event, which should fire when loading of image to imageview is finished. Sadly, I know for sure that it doesn't mean that the image has been displayed!

I need to know when there is image on this additional screen, because I need to precisely measure for how long it is shown. I also tried checking if my imageview "isDirty" and I also noticed, that even after my this method returns false (so image view isn't dirty anymore) there is still some time between this (imageview stops being dirty) and an actual drawing of image on the screen.

Does Android provide any mechanism that will fire after image has really been displayed on screen? Even if it requires some hacking, digging into NDK etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [GlobalLayoutListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener) to figure out when you're view has been drawn. Example implementation:

```
yourImageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            yourImageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            //Put your measurements here.
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've checked this and it works fine. However I don't remove listener and I have to count how many times it fires. After second onGlobalLayout event the image is present on additional screen, so it solves my issue. Many thanks!